# Kohana ORM диапозоны поиск

Tags: поиск, php, kohana

Добрый день ,прошу помочь с простой задачой на мой взгляд но я никак не соображу (
Имеется форма с двумя значениями:

- input - От (минимальное значение)
- input - До (Максимальное значение)

Имеется два поля в базе

- start
- end

Задача: к примеру пользователь ищет приемлемый себе пляж, вводит значение от и значение до. Согласно этим значениям должен осуществятся поиск в базе среди полей start и end.

Поиск по базе делаю так:

```
$query = ORM::factory('Object');

        $query->or_where_open();

        if (!empty($data['beech_start']) && !empty($data['beech_end'])) {
        $query->where('beech_start','>=',$data['beech_start']);
        $query->and_where('beech_end','<=',$data['beech_end']);
        }

        $query->or_where_close();
$messages = $query->order_by('created','DESC')->limit($pagination->items_per_page)->offset($pagination->offset)->reset(FALSE)->find_all();
```

Совсем туплю, товарищи, задача вроде тривиальная, очень прошу помощи.

Comment: А в чём же проблема?

Answer (score 1):

а зачем вообще ->or_where_open() и ->or_where_close()? Без них, имхо, всё должно работать

Comment: я кусок выдрал ,без них или с ними я пробывал не имело разницы

Comment: в каком формате идёт сравнение? Какого типа данные в БД и какие приходят в $data?

Answer (score -1):

лично я не люблю empty и делал бы через isset. Замените чтоль. А так не совсем понятно что не работает, если нужно найти в промежутке "... WHERE start>=1 AND end<=3 ..."

Comment: Слегка ни о чём. Почему ``isset()``, а не ``empty()``?  
Условия для поиска в промежутке у человека присутствует.

Comment: если $data['beech_start'] = 0? EMPTY выдаст его как несуществующий оператор && не оставляет шансов на успешное выполнение. и в промежутке от 0 до 100 например, я не получу результата.

Comment: а если пустая строка или ``false``?

Comment: проверку он проходит ,я пробывал выводить через var_dump значения уже после условия они есть,

Comment: @xEdelweiss, Если пустая строка, то не выполнять этот промежуток (как один из вариантов)

if (is_numeric(isset($data['beech_start'])) {$query->where('beech_start','>=',$data['beech_start']);}

if (is_numeric(isset($data['beech_end'])) {$query->where('beech_end','<=',$data['beech_end']);}

Привел как легкий пример. Поэтому я абсолютно не вижу смысла в вашем минусе))

Comment: if (isset($data['beech_start']) && isset($data['beech_end'])) {
$query->or_where_open()->where('beech_start','>=',$data['beech_start'])->and_where('beech_end','<=',$data['beech_end'])->or_where_close();
}
Если и так не правильно, то мне кажется ошибка совсем не в этом

Comment: @Manitikyl, посмотрите на время минуса и время коммента - сможете сделать определенный вывод.